# redshift sql how to handle infinite values

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a number of  datasets that I am trying to load into amazon redhsift from s3 buckets. Here is my command:

```
"copy tablename from 'my_s3_bucket' iam_role 'my_role' delimiter ',' IGNOREHEADER 1 null as ''
```

this works but for some files throws an error:

```
Invalid digit, Value 'i', Pos 0, Type: Decimal...
```

On inspection the data has 'inf' in some positions which is causing the error. I am wondering if there is a way to handle infinite values with this type of command? Or simply upload it as a null - though I have '' already specified as null so not sure if I can do another?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change table's schema to load data as `VARCHAR` and then create a view with a `CASE` statement handling `inf` values and cast values to proper data type.